# Is jQuery's $(selector).eq(index) and $(selector)[index] the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between all these ways?

```
//1
$('div').eq(index) 

//2
$('div')[index] 

//3
$($('div')[index] )

//4
$('div').get(1)
```

Are they same?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Of course. I got the same output in chrome developer console

Comment: Then something is seriously wrong with your browser, call Google and complain at once!

Comment: @adeneo Ah, you angry ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No.

The *first* and the *third* return jQuery object, while the *second* and the *forth* return DOM element:

```
$("div").eq(index) === $($("div")[index]);  // --> jQuery object

$("div")[index] === $("div").get(index);    // --> DOM element
```

You can read about the last case here: **http://api.jquery.com/get/**.

If you need to see the difference between types you may try to run the following in the console:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call($("div").eq(index)); // "[object Object]"
Object.prototype.toString.call($("div")[index]);    // "[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

Answer (score 3):

`First and third` will get you `jQuery` object and second one will give you `DOM` object.

1. `$('div').eq(index)`   *// will return jquery object*
2. `$('div')[index]`      *// will give you javascript DOM object*
3. `$($('div')[index])`   *//will give you jQuery object by converting DOM object*

You require different syntax to get the properties  for instance for `id` of object.

```
idofobject = $('div').eq(index).attr('id') //jQuery

idofobject = $('div')[index].id            //javascript
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('div').eq(index)`
This returns a JQuery object

`$('div')[index]`
this will give you javascript object

Answer (score 1):

- v1: `$('div').eq(index)` :: returns a jQuery-wrapped collection comprising one div.
- v2: `$('div')[index]` :: returns a reference to a DOM element (not jQuery-wrapped)
- v3: `$($('div')[index])` :: returns a jQuery-wrapped collection comprising one div. This is a verbose and inefficient version of the v1.

You didn't ask about `$('div').get(index)`, which is another way of achieving v2. AFAIK, it is not substantially less efficient.